# Is there a way to capture packages by using tcpdump with ipset?

Tags: tcpdump, ipset

I got a big ipset and I want to capture networking packages related/not-related to these IPs.

Is there a way to capture packages by using tcpdump with ipset as param?

Comment: This might be an approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073203

Comment: Theoretically all need to capture the package that gets affect by iptables(using ipset). Well sure I will try this one. Just to add a little more iptables-rules. Thank you.